# DataTrigger not firing when property changed in DataGrid SelectedItem

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to have a datatrigger fire when I update a property on my DataGrid for the SelectedItem. Can someone show me what I need to change to get it to work?

When a user selects an item in the grid, its Connected property gets set to true. My label in the DataGrid is supposed to change from red to green. It stays red.

I know the style works because if I start out with the property Connected set to true, they all come out green. It just does not seem to fire when the user selects an item in the DataGrid.

```
// Style set in Resources of my control
<Style x:Key="ConnectedStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}" 
BasedOn="{StaticResource FontAwesome}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />    // I added this last 
minute thinking it might need to be initialized but still nothing.
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Connected}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Connected}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>


<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AvailablePorts}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPort}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    Style="{StaticResource PlainGrid}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnHeaderHeight="30">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" Status" Width="55">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource ConnectedStyle}" 
                     Content="&#xf111;" FontSize="12" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                     Padding="0" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" Port" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Port}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

View Model

```
public class EMSViewModel : ViewModelDetailBase<EMSViewModel, EMSModel>
{

    public ObservableCollection<AvailablePortsModel> AvailablePorts
    {
        get
        {
            return this.availablePorts;
        }

        private set
        {
            this.availablePorts = value;

            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.AvailablePorts);
        }
    }

    public AvailablePortsModel SelectedPort
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedPort;
        }

        set
        {
            this.selectedPort = value;

            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.SelectedPort);

            this.ConnectToPort();
        }
    }

    private void ConnectToPort()
    {
        // if the code (removed) evaluates to true, set the connected property to true.

        this.SelectedPort.Connected = true;

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.AvailablePorts);
    }
}
```

Model

```
namespace FastV.Models
{
    using SimpleMvvmToolkit;
    public class AvailablePortsModel : ModelBase<AvailablePortsModel>
    {
        private bool connected;

        private string port;

        public bool Connected
        {
            get
            {
                return this.connected;
            }

            set
            {
                this.connected = value;

                this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.Connected);
            }
        }

        public string Port
        {
            get
            {
                return this.port;
            }

            set
            {
                this.port = value;

                this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.Port);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did a quick test using the code you have here, and it all works OK. The label color changes to green as soon as I select the row. Do you have any other code that might be interfering with this, such as setting the Foreground color somewhere else such as one of the base styles?

Comment: Ditto -- I just finished trying your code and it works fine for me. The only difference is I wrote my own quickie implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`. But if the `ModelBase` implementation works for your viewmodel, I can't imagine it wouldn't work for `AvailablePortsModel` as well. That is, assuming that is what your viewmodel is using; you didn't include the whole class definition.

Comment: I've added the class definition for my ViewModel. I'll continue looking at it and try to see where I might have something blocking my implementation from working.

Comment: @MikeCollins One thing I find immensely helpful is to put a trace on a binding. First add this namespace to the Window/UserControl/whatever tag: `xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"`. Then add this to your DataTrigger Bindings: `{Binding Connected, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}`. That'll give you a lot of information in the VS Output pane when the Binding is updated. If when you click on the grid, you *don't* get that flood of information, that might mean ModelBase isn't firing the notification as it should (though I've no clue why it wouldn't).